# What's the StringBuilder equivalent in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, angular5, typescript2.0, c#-6.0

So I have this string that contains a percentage symbol `%`. I want to be able to replace it with the `#` symbol using TypeScript. I am still learning TypeScript so its syntax is still throwing me off. I managed to implement the solution that I need in C# and that piece of code can be found below:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string data = "AHu%odk"; // The % character will always be at index 3
    string finalResult = "";
    if (data.Contains("%"))
    {
        StringBuilder sbFirstIndex = new StringBuilder(data);
        sbFirstIndex[3] = '#';
        finalResult = sbFirstIndex.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Appended string now looks like this: {0} \n", finalResult);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False. It does not contain it");
    }
}
```

Here is my TypeScript implementation but I got stuck if checking for the index of the character:

```
changePercantage(input: string): void {
    var data = "AHu%odk";
    var finalResult = "";
    var index = result.indexOf("%");

    if (index == 3) {
        // Replace the percentage with the # character
    }
}
```

The version of TypeScript that I am using is 2.3.3.0.

Angular: 5.0.0

Node.js: 8.9.3

Npm: v5.6.0

Comment: Here is post I recently submitted to address your question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/stringbuilder-to-build-or-not-to-build

Comment: This question has got nothing to do with `StringBuilder()` equivalent as mentioned in the title. This question is about string replacement. I think you should change the title because it is really confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TypeScript, for string replacement, use a regular expression:

```js
function changePercentage(input) {
    return input.replace(/%/, "#");
}

console.log(changePercentage("AHu%odk"));
```